# JNLP FileSaveService opens a file open dialog

Tags: swing, jnlp, java-web-start

Hi I'm trying to save a file from a Java Webstart Application.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         FileSaveService fos = (FileSaveService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.FileSaveService");
         //open Dialog
         FileContents fc = fos.saveFileDialog("c:/data", null, new ByteArrayInputStream("Hallo Welt".getBytes()), "name.txt");
         System.out.println("FileContents: " + fc);
      } catch (UnavailableServiceException e) {
         System.err.println("***" + e + "***");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("***" + e + "***");
      }
      //wait a minute
      try {
         Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Everything works except that the dialog that comes up looks like a "open" file dialog, not like a "save" file dialog:

[image: FileDialog]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might compare your `fss.saveFileDialog()` parameters to those shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#FileSaveService).

Comment: I just tried the [File Service demo](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) in 1.7.0_21-b11 (Windows 32 bit) and the open & save dialogs appeared as expected.  What make & model JRE are the users running?

Comment: We're using JRE version 1.6.0_31-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: I tried the code from trashgods link with the same results. I used this JRE: Java Web Start 10.13.2.20
Using JRE version 1.7.0_13-b20 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: @AndrewThompson you were right, I should have checked with the newest JDK much earlier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in JRE bersion 1.7.0_21-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

And there it is: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2227257

Answer (score 1):

The File-Open-dialog is necessary. You first need to let the user choose where to save the data. Thus a previous call to openFileDialog is absolute necessary for a jnlp-application. You are not allowed to directly save to a specific location like c:

If you follow the mentioned link (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#FileSaveService) you should be successful.

EDIT:
for clarification.
Saving via javax.jnlp.FileSaveService does exactly need one call. For instance calling saveFileDialog() like this should be sufficient:

```
fss.saveFileDialog(null, null, new ByteArrayInputStream("Hallo Welt".getBytes()    ), "newFileName.txt");
```

The necessity of one User-Dialogue is due to the anonymizing nature of jnlp, where your application should not get any hint about the user-filesystem.
However, I have to admit, that this was not your question.

Your main trouble comes from the java app everytime presenting the "open-dialogue" instead of the "save-dialogue".

This should not happen! If I may humbly assume from your snippet where you call `fos.saveFileDialog`: did you just initialize fos by the FileOpenService instead of the FileSaveService?

More details on the FileSaveService can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileSaveService.html

Comment: When I run the code in the example in the link, I see 3 times an open dialog. What did you see?